# Convert Object to String error when list.contacts()) is called

Tags: java

This is giving me an error:

```
for(String contact : list.contacts())
{
    contact1.append(contact);
}
```

and corresponds to this:

```
public List<String> contacts(){
   List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
   Node currentNode = head;
   while(currentNode != null){  
      myList.add(currentNode.toString() + "\n");
      currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
    }
   return myList;
}
```

Comment: What is the error?  and what is 'list'.  Please provide more code so we can help you.

Comment: is list your custom list or one jdk provides?

Comment: this method is undefined @immibis

Comment: @user3668053 what is contact1?

Comment: which method is undefined ?

Answer (score -1):

You are getting values from list.and in list all the values object type.

```
for(Object contact : list.contacts()){
contact1.append(contact);}
```